# How to bypass the cross origin error using angular 6 (Firefox CORS Error, Chrome Preflight Error)

Tags: java, angular, httpclient, angular6

I am developing a front end to be used as a client for a rest-api. Angular 6 is used.

The problem is that when I send a post request using HttpClient, I get this cross origin error.
my code:

## Service:

```
export class ApiConfigLogin {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        private dataSrvc: DataService) {}

      private _url = this.dataSrvc.getMainUrl() + '/sec-login';

      private options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      };
      getResults(reqbody): Observable < ApiConfigLoginInterface > {
        console.log(this._url);
        return this.http.post < ApiConfigLoginInterface > (this._url, reqbody, this.options);
      }
    }
```

## Component.ts

```
this._ApiConfigLogin.getResults(body)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.enableForms();
        if (data.status === 401) {
          this.lowerMessage = data.message;
        } else {
          console.log(1);
        }
      });
```

in mozilla firefox:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://8888.8888.8888.8888:8888/address/sec-login. (Reason:
>   CORS request did not succeed).

in google chrome:

> Failed to load
>   http://8888.8888.8888.8888:8888/address/sec-login: Response for
>   preflight is invalid (redirect)

I have tested Allow control extensions to my browsers. It is good to know that I have a content-type header:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS errors occur when you call a service using a URL that is not the same as the URL used to load the Web app, up to and including the port. This is a security feature built into your browsers.

To avoid it, your *server* needs to allow cross-origin requests by adding headers. You can manually add the headers, which takes a bit of effort, or, if you are using something like Spring, there will be an annotation.

Comment: thanks Steve, so there is not much to do on client side, yeah?

Comment: Yes. Doing things on the client side essentially subverts browser security. That was my first inclination, until I read the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

there are ways around the it; See [this](https://gist.github.com/jesperorb/6ca596217c8dfba237744966c2b5ab1e) on GitHub about how to handle CORSS client-side:

> **JSONP**
>
> *WARNING: This isn't allowed on every API and may break when calling certain APIS*
>
> You can bypass CORS in production using JSONP which stands for JSON
>   with Padding and is kinda also a 'hack'. But it is a widely used hack
>   which many APIs support. You are not sending a pure JSON-request but
>   you are wrapping your data in a function that gets evaluated. JSONP
>   explained in the link below:

or use a proxy:

> **Proxy**
>
> WARNING: Great services, but you are dependent on these services
>   to work, if they break or go down, so does your app
>
> You can use a service that proxies your request and automatically
>   enable CORS for your:
>
> - https://crossorigin.me/
> - https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/
> - [More Proxies here](https://gist.github.com/jimmywarting/ac1be6ea0297c16c477e17f8fbe51347)

Then you have to call your API by prepending one of these URLs to your request, for example:

> - https://crossorigin.me/http://yourapi.com
> - https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://yourapi.com